Faking template virtual function in C++
I would like to simplify this convoluted piece of code:
class Device {
protected:
  int base;
  int size;
  // other

public:
  virtual uint64_t load(uint64_t addr, uint64_t size) = 0;
  virtual void store(uint64_t addr, uint64_t value, uint64_t size) = 0;
  // other
};

class Dram : protected Device {
private:
  std::array<uint8_t, 1024> data;

public:
  uint64_t load(uint64_t addr, uint64_t size) override
  {
    ram_specific_load();

    switch (size) {
    case 8: return data[addr];
    case 16: return *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(data.data() + addr);
    case 32: return *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(data.data() + addr);
    case 64: return *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(data.data() + addr);
    default: return 0;
    }
  }

  void store(uint64_t addr, uint64_t value, uint64_t size) override
  {
    ram_specific_store();

    switch (size) {
    case 8:
        data[addr] = value;
        break;
    case 16:
        *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(data.data() + addr) = value;
        break;
    case 32:
        *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(data.data() + addr) = value;
        break;
    case 64:
        *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(data.data() + addr) = value;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
  }

  // other
};

// other devices

then it was used like that:
std::vector<Device*> devices;

devices.push_back(&Dram());
devices.push_back(&Gpu());
...

devices[1]->store(0x1234, devices[0]->load(0x4321, 64), 64);

uint32_t var = devices[1]->load(0x1212, 32);

I tried overloading operator[] instead of using load/store functions, but it turns out some devices need to distinguish between load/store operation to call an additional function.
uint64_t& operator[](uint64_t addr)
{
  if (is_loading())
    foo1();
  else
    foo2();
  
  return data[addr];
}

I tried making them template functions to handle the data size, but they cannot be template and virtual at the same time. The functions should be virtual to not break the Device-inherited abstraction.
I tried using CRTP, but it also makes the devices not very Base-class compatible.
I need to keep the "container of base class objects" abstraction as sometimes i don't know what type of device i am operating on, just have a base address and need to find the device in all devices.

If you know all your device types at compile time.... maybe look into having a std::vector<std::variant<Dram,Gpu>>.  And then use std::visit

Should all devices be capable of load/store of 8,16,32 and 64 bit words? Instead of templates, why not load8, load16 etc.? Overriding those isn't a problem

"overloading operator[] instead of using load/store functions, but it turns out some devices need to distinguish between load/store operation" operator[] might return a wrapper, would have operator= to store and converting operator for load.

You can add a template function and/or other functions in the base class which calls the virtual functions with the correct parameters
class Device {
protected:
  int base;
  int size;
  // other

public:
  virtual uint64_t load(uint64_t addr, uint64_t size) = 0;
  virtual void store(uint64_t addr, uint64_t value, uint64_t size) = 0;
  // other

  // templates
  template<class T> 
  uint64_t 
  load(uint64_t addr)
  {
    return static_cast<T>(this->load(addr, sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT);
  }

  template<class T> 
  void 
  store(uint64_t addr, T value)
  {
    this->store(addr, static_cast<uint64_t>(value), sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT);
  }

  // Non-template functions
  uint64_t 
  load64(uint64_t addr)
  {
    return this->load(addr, 64);
  }

  void 
  store64(uint64_t addr, uint64_t value)
  {
    this->store(addr, value, 64);
  }

  // load32/store32 etc.
};

Now your example would look like
devices[1]->store(0x1234, devices[0]->load<uint64_t>(0x4321));
devices[1]->store64(0x1234, devices[0]->load64(0x4321));

uint32_t var1 = devices[1]->load<uint32_t>(0x1212);
uint32_t var2 = devices[1]->load32(0x1212);

If you want to use array access semantics, then you could use a proxy to defer to the correct load/store operations (as @Jarod42 suggested)
class Device {
  // all of the above

  struct Proxy {
    Device* dev;
    uint64_t addr;

    // The proxy uses the template load/store

    // Conversion operator. Invoked if this is the
    // right-hand side of the assignment.
    template<class T> 
    operator T() 
    {
      return this->dev->load<T>(this->addr);
    }

    // Assignment operator. Invoked if this is the
    // left-hand side of the assignment.
    template<class T> 
    Proxy 
    operator=(T value)
    {
      this->dev->store(this->addr, value);
      return *this;
    }

  };

  Proxy 
  operator[](uint64_t addr) {
    return Proxy{this, addr};
  }
};

The proxy wont know which type you want to access the memory as until you store it in a temporary variable with the correct type, so the one-liner examples cannot be done unless extra functions are provided (or using an ugly cast)
uint64_t tmp = (*devices[0])[0x4321];
(*devices[1])[0x1234] = tmp;

(*devices[0])[0x4321] = static_cast<uint64_t>((*devices[1])[0x1234]);

uint32_t var = (*devices[1])[0x1212];

This can be fixed by adding the functions to the proxy
struct Proxy {
  // All of the above

  uint64_t
  as64()
  {
    return *this; // Invokes the conversion operator
  }

  // as32 etc.
};

Finally, the example would look like
(*devices[1])[0x1234] = (*devices[0])[0x4321].as64();

The array access operators probably looks better with references though
auto& dev0 = *devices[0];
auto& dev1 = *devices[1];
dev1[0x1234] = dev0[0x4321].as64();

uint32_t var = dev1[0x1212];

If you don't want to put this code directly in the base class, you can simply create a wrapper and put it there instead
struct DeviceView {
  Device* dev;

  // The above device functionality, 
  // but replace this with this->dev
};

DeviceView{devices[1]}[0x1234] = DeviceView{devices[0]}[0x4321].as64();

uint32_t var = DeviceView{devices[1]}[0x1212];

This will not simplify the implementation of the derived classes though, as they still have to override the same virtual functions, but the usage of the hierarchy will be much simpler (and look a lot better).
(This code has not been tested or even compiled, so typos are to be expected).
